# Birt report design validating report parameters while running the report

Tags: javascript, eclipse, modal-dialog, birt

How to validate the report parameters while running the report in WebViewer. I am using the eclipse to design the reports. I am using the date fields and some select boxes as parameters. But my requirement is - user should not type the date, he should select the date from date picker(jquery UI) and at select boxes I want some kind of validation at server side that is **From Category** select  box should not be greater than **To Category** select box. I need to do this validation at server side with ajax calls. Is there any way to customize the dialog box to get this functionality or I should design new page to do that and link that report after validation.

I need export functionality also in my page, if i want that how to pass the selected parameters(Export Format, Pages, Auto) to report.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not think there is a way to validate the report parameters, the way you want to from the current dialog box. I am not sure I understand your export requirement. Can you please clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

**1 Validate Selectbox Parameters**

For the validation of your Select Parameters, you could use a Cascading Parameter Group.

First you create a Data Set that is returning the possible values for your "from Category". Then you reate a `New Cascading Parameter Group` and select `Multiple Data Set` add a new Paramter(your "from Categroy Prameter") and select the just created Data Set to display.

Close the Parameter group for now, and create a second Data Set that is returning the possible values for your "to Category". Here you can use the Input of your "from Categroy Prameter" form the just created Cascading Parameter Group to limit the results to display.

Now go back to your Cascading Parameter Group and add a second Paramter based on your second Data Set. Make sure both parameters are configured as List Boxes.

If you now select a value for your "from Category" the allowed values for "to Category" will be dynamically updated.
[image: Cascading Parameter Group]

**2 Export input parameters for export formats**

To export your input parameters simply add them by drag and drop to your Report Page. Parameters can be displayed in every Expression Field with be binding `params["parameterName"]`. If you just want to display them for a limited kind of Export Formats (e.g. display in .xsl but hide for .html) select the visibility Tab in the Property Editor and select "hide Element" "for specific outputs..." and select the format where you want to hide the field.

[image: hide Element]

**3 Datepicker Input**

there is no plugin that I know that is providing the Requirement to BIRT out of the box. You can edit the `.jsp` that is taking the input parameters but here you are on your own. I would prefere to display the Input-Format of a date e.g. `dd.MM.yyyy` to reduce typo errors.