# BIRT using user input. When input only contains part of the value, the drop down box will show the matching records. how to achieve that?

Tags: birt

Hi I have a question regarding the parameter in BIRT reports. Basically, I want to have a user input as parameter. When user's type in the input, it doesn't need to be the complete record in db, as long as it matches partially the record in db. For example, the database has a record KVM0203, when the user typed in "KVM", I would like to have a drop down list that shows everything start with KVM. How to achieve that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a cascading parameter group. The first input from the user is a String parameter. On this parameter you need to append a `%` and do a [`LIKE` query](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_like.asp) on your database creating a new data set as result. This data set is than used as source for a select box input value with all possible values matching the first parameter.

[have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36884893/1515052) for some pictures from another usecase.